# Inheriting a datatemplate and manipulating the background color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate

I have the following datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate
    x:Key="SourceControlCommitDataTemplate"
    DataType="{x:Type SourceControl:SourceControlCommitViewModel}">
    <Border
        BorderBrush="LightGray"
        BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
        >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Padding="0 5 0 0"
                Margin="3,0,0,0"
                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
                Text="{Binding Message}"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="3 0 0 0"
                Padding="0 0 0 3"
                Foreground="Gray"
                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
                Text="{Binding Author}"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Margin="0 0 3 0"
                Padding="0 0 0 3"
                Foreground="Gray"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
                Text="{Binding Date}"
                />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use this datatemplate for a list of objects that I display in a Listbox. 
I want to use the same datatemplate, only one where I bind the background color to a property. So i need one listbox with colors and one just plain. I could reproduce the entire code and maybe use a datatemplate selector (although not completely sure how to use those) but that seems overly verbose and repetitive, is there not a simple way to overload a property throughout the template or something to that effect?

Answer (score 0):

Use the template as-is for the one that doesn't need special colors. For the other, use this:

```
<DataTemplate
    x:Key="ColoredSourceControlCommitDataTemplate"
    DataType="{x:Type SourceControl:SourceControlCommitViewModel}"
    >
    <Border 
        Background="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}"
        >
        <ContentControl
            Content="{Binding}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SourceControlCommitDataTemplate}"
            />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Or use `DataTemplate.Triggers` instead of a converter.

You might need to fiddle around with `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` etc. but that's the general idea.

Comment: This did not successfully change the color. The code is hitting a breakpoint that I set in my converter, but the changes do not get reflected. Even if i hardcode a color (like your original example) it does not make the necessary changes)

Comment: I tried wrapping my original data template in a ContentControl to see if that helped but no cigar

Comment: Try wrapping the ContentControl in a Border and set the Background on the Border. I'm on my phone in a restaurant so it's tough to update my example

Comment: @JacobAlley If you haven't gotten this working, I'd like to see the complete code for your version, including the relevant part(s) of `SourceControlCommitViewModel` and the value converter. Chances are it's something pretty simple. If the parts are defined right, this stuff is bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there not a simple way to overload a property throughout the template or something to that effect?

No, a `DataTemplate` is always defined as a whole. You cannot base a template on another one like you can with a `Style`.

But you could bind to a source property and use a `FallbackValue` that kicks in when the source property is not found, e.g.:

```
<Border Background="{Binding Background, FallbackValue=Transparent}"
    BorderBrush="LightGray"
    BorderThickness="0 0 0 1">
...
```